# remove duplicates in list, but keep one copy

Tags: python, duplicates

Say I have a list

```
list = ["1","2","1","3"]
```

and I want to get rid of the duplicate 1's but I want to keep one copy so the list would read

```
list = ["1","2","3"]
```

I know I can use set() to get rid of the duplicates, but I will not be able to keep a copy. How would I go about keeping a copy?

Comment: What do you mean by keeping a copy? If you make a set out of that list, the list will stay intact.

Comment: The answer you've shown is exactly what you would get from converting your list to a set, ignoring issues of ordering...

Comment: @Francisco Couzo oh... woops i'm sorry, I haven't actually wrote the code yet and when reading about set() I was under the assumption it removed all the duplicates, and didn't keep any of them. So simply using set() would work?

Answer (score 2):

use `set`  and then convert it to `list` again

```
lists = ["1","2","1","3"]
new_list = list(set(lists))
```